# I Create a custom module in Magento 2.0 (Add/Edit Customer Attribute) but i am faceing a problem in prepare grid in magento 2.0 backend

Tags: magento-2.0

I am using a sample module And there have a grid own table thats working but i need to change to \Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute collection and i have no idea where and how many place i change?

**weblog_blog_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="weblog_blog_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**weblog_blog_grid_block.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="weblog.grid.container">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="weblog.grid" as="grid">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">weblogGrid</argument>
                    <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">SR\Weblog\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPosts\Collection</argument>
                    <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                    <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                    <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction" name="admin.block.weblog.grid.massaction" as="grid.massaction">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="massaction_id_field" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                        <argument name="form_field_name" xsi:type="string">blogpost</argument>
                        <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="delete" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">weblog/*/massDelete</item>
                                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete?</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="weblog.grid.columnSet">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="path" xsi:type="string">cannedresponse/*/edit</item>
                            <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getId</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="title">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">title</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">title</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="publish_date">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Publish Date</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">date</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">publish_date</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">publish_date</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="is_active">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enabled</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="SR\Weblog\Model\Status"/>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">is_active</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">is_active</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="action">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">action</argument>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Action</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">action</argument>
                            <argument name="getter" xsi:type="string">getId</argument>
                            <argument name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">weblog</argument>
                            <argument name="is_system" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                            <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="view_action" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                                    <item name="url" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="base" xsi:type="string">weblog/*/edit</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="field" xsi:type="string">blogpost_id</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-actions</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-actions</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Export" name="admin.block.weblog.grid.export" as="grid.export">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="exportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">weblog/*/exportCsv</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="excel" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">weblog/*/exportXml</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>enter preformatted text here
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**weblog_blog_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="weblog_blog_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PostGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">blogpost_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">blogpost_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="weblog/blog/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="disable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="weblog/blog/massDisable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="enable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="weblog/blog/massEnable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="weblog_blog_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">weblog_blog_listing.weblog_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">blogpost_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="blogpost_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="publish_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Publish Date</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="is_active">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\IsActive</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="SR\Weblog\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostAction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">blogpost_id</item>
                    <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">weblog/blog/edit</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">blogpost_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="weblog_blog_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">SR\Weblog\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPosts\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="SR\Weblog\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPosts\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">blog_posts</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">blog_posts_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">blog_posts_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">SR\Weblog\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPosts</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="PostGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">SR\Weblog\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPosts\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">WeblogPostGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="WeblogPostGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
   <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" type="SR\Weblog\Block\Reg" /> 
   <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" type="SR\Weblog\Block\Edit" /> 
</config>
```

So Please Help How can i change grid to EAV OR any core module collection or also you can tell me how can create grid in MAGENNO 2.0

Comment: Show your grid code with details.

Comment: weblog_blog_index.xml
{}

Comment: eav grid is different from other. It has 4 type that means catalog, customer etc. You can go with catalog first. I separate this but if I post this it will too long.

Comment: don't you can explain me any grid like as customer as small
I need only how can create grid

Comment: Check last updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Controller file

```
app/code/SR/EavCollectionGrid/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php
```

```
namespace SR\EavCollectionGrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->createActionPage();
        $resultPage->addContent(
            $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock('SR\EavCollectionGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute')
        );
        return $resultPage;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Phrase|null $title
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    protected function createActionPage($title = null)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Catalog'), __('Catalog'))
            ->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Product Attributes'), __('Manage Product Attributes'))
            ->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog::catalog_attributes_attributes');
        if (!empty($title)) {
            $resultPage->addBreadcrumb($title, $title);
        }
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Eav Collection Grid'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Create app/code/SR/EavCollectionGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute.php

```
namespace SR\EavCollectionGrid\Block\Adminhtml;

class Attribute extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_attribute';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'SR_EavCollectionGrid';
        $this->_headerText = __('Eav Collection Grid');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add New Custom Attribute');
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

Create app/code/SR/EavCollectionGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Grid.php

```
/**
 * attributes grid
 *
 * @author     Magento Core Team 
 */
namespace SR\EavCollectionGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 */
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \SR\EavCollectionGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \SR\EavCollectionGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \SR\EavCollectionGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_module = 'eavcollectiongrid';
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Block Module
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_module = 'adminhtml';

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('attributeGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('attribute_code');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare product attributes grid collection object
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare default grid column
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->addColumn(
            'attribute_code',
            [
                'header' => __('Attribute Code'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'attribute_code',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-attr-code',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-attr-code'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'frontend_label',
            [
                'header' => __('Default label'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'frontend_label',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-label',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-label'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'is_required',
            [
                'header' => __('Required'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'is_required',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => ['1' => __('Yes'), '0' => __('No')],
                'header_css_class' => 'col-required',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-required'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'is_user_defined',
            [
                'header' => __('System'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'is_user_defined',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => [
                    '0' => __('Yes'), // intended reverted use
                    '1' => __('No'), // intended reverted use
                ],
                'header_css_class' => 'col-system',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-system'
            ]
        );

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return url of given row
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl($this->_module . '/*/edit', ['attribute_id' => $row->getAttributeId()]);
    }
}
```

Create app/code/SR/EavCollectionGrid/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute/Collection.php

```
namespace SR\EavCollectionGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute;

/**
 * attribute resource collection
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Collection
{
    /**
     * Entity factory1
     *
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory
     */
    protected $_eavEntityFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_eavEntityFactory = $eavEntityFactory;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $eavConfig, $connection, $resource);
    }

    /**
     * Resource model initialization
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute',
            'Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute'
        );
    }
}
```

Create app/code/SR/EavCollectionGrid/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute.php

```
namespace SR\EavCollectionGrid\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\LockValidatorInterface;

/**
 * Catalog attribute resource model
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team 
 */
class Attribute extends \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute
{
    /**
     * Eav config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var LockValidatorInterface
     */
    protected $attrLockValidator;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Type $eavEntityType
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param LockValidatorInterface $lockValidator
     * @param string $connectionName
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Type $eavEntityType,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        LockValidatorInterface $lockValidator,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {
        $this->attrLockValidator = $lockValidator;
        $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $storeManager, $eavEntityType, $connectionName);
    }
}
```

Download full module from [here](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-eavcollectiongrid)

Comment: Code Is working .But tell me why you not use listing_grid as magneto xml all code written in single file

Comment: I just use magento default attribute grid. You can create grid using ui_component too.

Comment: This is difficult and One Thing more in this file
app/code/SR/EavCollectionGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Grid.php

in this statement 
$this->_module = 'eavcollectiongrid';
Can you tell me in briefly

Comment: This define block module. if you not set then it's adminhtml by default

Comment: I extension add or edit section not working in UBANTU but complete run in windows

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pa5sefduhx0fvxm/Auriga%20%283%29.zip?dl=0

Comment: change 'View' to 'view'.

Comment: I was change now it is working but all section load left side and back,add new ,save and edit button not showing

Comment: Check all file name. Unix system strictly maintain name convention. Clear magento cache too. Working nice in my mac.

Comment: Hello Sohel,
Can You suggest me for 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92708/magenot-2-0-create-order-by-quote-how-to-submit-quote-to-convert-in-order