# Magento 2.0 Create Order by quote .How to submit quote to convert in order

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I have set all information in quote but how can i submit ?

```
$quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);
//Set Shipping Method
$quote->setShippingMethod('carriers_flatrate');
$quote->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');
//Set Payment method
$quote->getPayment()->importData( array('method' => 'cashondelivery'));

// Inventory will not update
$quote->setInventoryProcessed(true);
$quote->save();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
$quote->setCustomerEmail('admin@example.com');
$quoteManagement = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface');

$order = $quoteManagement->submit($quote, ['increment_id' => '100000001']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some suggestions for you, you find all function necessary to submit quote in `app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php`.

This model implements and override by `app/code/Magento/Quote/Api/CartManagementInterface.php` in `app/code/Magento/Quote/etc/di.xml`

Comment: Why we need to override ?

Comment: Yes this code is running

$quoteManagement = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement');

        $order = $quoteManagement->submit($quote);

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: Yes . This code creating a order in backend